# PowerShell not parsing data inside square bracket from HTML

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to parse data from a webpage using PowerShell where part of it looks like below and is trying to get the value inside "key_as_string". The HTML snippet below shows part of the html code where I use th query `$doc.getElementsByTagName("div")[290]` where it gave a result but doesn't include the data inside the bracket and just shows `[]` (see the image of the PowerShell result below).

I've read somewhere that PowerShell doesn't like square brackets, which might be the reason it's not getting the data. Is there any way this can be accomplish with PowerShell? Or a better way to do it other than PowerShell?

```json
"buckets": [
        {
          "key_as_string": "2019-03-04T13:00:00.000-06:00",
          "key": 1551726000000,
          "doc_count": 1
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "status": 200
}
```

Webpage snippet:

[image: Screenshot 1]

HTML snippet.

[image: Screenshot 2]

PowerShell result:

[image: Screenshot 3]

Comment: That's JSON. Use `ConvertFrom-Json` on it.

Comment: Your code is far too incomplete for us to debug the issue. Please create a [mcve] and update your question with it. Also, please avoid posting screenshots of text. Copy/paste the actual text.